# My bool function keeps returning true and im not sure why

Tags: c++, arrays, function, boolean

Im doing an excercise sheet to get an understanding of functions and I am currently working on the following question.

Write function prototypes for each of the following:

1. A function HasValue that may be passed a reference to an array, the size of the array and a
   search value. The function should return true if the search value exists in the array

In my code I have sent the contents of the array, the array size and the value to be searched in the array to the bool function.

In the function I compared the value to each element of the array using a for loop.

I then created a variable count in the function that will be incremented if the value matches any element in the array.

I then used an if else statment to return `true` if count is greater than 0 and `false` if count is equal to 0. The problem is however that the function is only returning true thus the output will always be "this number appears in the array"

Logically these steps seem correct to me but obviously there is a flaw somewhere that I cant see. I presume its just I do not have a decent understanding of Bool functions yet but if someone could explain where and why I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated in my learning process to understanding functions and c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

bool HasValue(int Array[], int size, int Value);

int main()
{
    int value;
    int Array[10]{ 3,5,6,8,9,1,2,14,12,43 };

    cout << "enter value you wish to search for in array " << endl;
    cin >> value;

    HasValue(Array, 10 , value);

    if (true)
        cout << "This number appears in the array " << endl;
    else
        cout << "This number does not appear in the array " << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool HasValue(int Array[], int size, int Value)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       if (Value == Array[i])
       {
           count++;
       }    
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger or add `cout` statements to see what your code is doing.

Comment: Note that `stdafx.h` should be the first non-whitespace, non-comment line in the file.

Comment: Well, you'll probably want to actually _use_ the return value, for one thing... ;)  `true` is a constant, so `if (true) { /* Line 1 */ } else { /* Line 2 */ }` will always execute `Line 1`.

Comment: Also, as an aside, `if (count > 0) { return true; } else { return false; }` can be shortened to `return (count > 0);`.  The parentheses aren't necessary, but they can improve readability.  This works because `count > 0` is already a boolean expression, so you can just return its result directly.

Answer (score 3):

You test code is the problem

```
HasValue(Array, 10 , value);
if (true)
    cout << "This number appears in the array " << endl;
else
    cout << "This number does not appear in the array " << endl;
```

This ignores the return value of `HasValue` and always prints `"This number appears in the array"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
HasValue(Array, 10 , value);
```

This line of code executes the function but ignores the returned value. When a function returns a value, you need to assign it to a variable:

```
bool result = HasValue(Array, 10 , value);
```

Then `if (true)` does not have any reference to the returned value. The `true` inside the if will cause the first `cout` to always print. You will never see the output from the `else`. But once you have the return value in a variable, you can use it in the `if`:

```
if(result)
```

You can reduce this all to one line of code, if you want:

```
if(HasValue(Array, 10 , value))
```

Now the `if` statement will directly test the return value from `HasValue()`. In this particular case, combining the code into a single line seems reasonable. You must be careful doing this, though. When you combine too much into a single line, the code becomes more difficult to debug. You will need to find a balance between readability and convenience as you continue learning how to program.